# Proving that $\phi$ is orthogonal to the harmonic forms given $\int\phi \;d\mathrm{vol}$.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

I want to prove that given a connected closed (compact without boundary) oriented Riemmanian manifold $(M,g)$, the condition
$$\int_M \varphi \;\mathrm{d}\mathrm{vol}_g=0$$
implies that $\int \varphi h \;\mathrm{d}\mathrm{vol}=0$ for every harmonic function $h$, i.e., every function such that $\triangle h:=(dd^*+d^*d)h=0$.

**Note:** *By the Hodge Decomposition Theorem, we have $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})=\mathrm{Ker}(\triangle) \oplus \mathrm{Im}(\triangle)$, so this would prove that the given condition implies the solution of the Poisson problem $\triangle f=\varphi$ for $\varphi$ smooth.*

In fact, the condition is also necessary, but that is easier to prove.

I know this condition must be true, but seen in this way it does not seem to obvious. It is saying that if it is orthogonal to the constant function $1$, then it is orthogonal to every harmonic function.

**Note 2:** There's a similar question made before. But the point is that I would not like to solve the Poisson equation appealing to PDE theory and instead try to prove it via the Hodge Decomposition Theorem (the standard PDE path is to use Riesz representation theorem and then elliptic regularity, but one needs Sobolev spaces and elliptic regularity; I have the intuition that there must be a simple proof using the Hodge decomposition argument).

Comment: By closed do you mean compact without boundary? If yes, only (locally) constant functions are harmonic. (Do you also assume that $M$ is connected?)

Comment: hmm... yes $M$ connected, that would make sense. I suppose it is trivial in that case...

Comment: If you put that into an answer I will be happy to accept it (that's all I need). Because then it is obvious why the condition implies what I want.

Comment: Could you just suggest why this is true (that they must be locally constant)?

Comment: As $H^0(M) \cong \mathbb R$ (as $M$ is connected), and $H^0(M)$ is generated by harmonic functions. That means there are only constant functions which are harmonic (or $H^0(M$ would not be one dimensional). Of course, you can also argue using maximum principle (a harmonic function does not have local maximum)

Comment: That's great! Thanks so much. That's all I needed. One thing that concerns me is that, since I am not familiar with the proof of the Hodge decomposition, I would be afraid if proving the existence of a solution is a circular argument. But I guess that is another question. Thanks!